# Clarification on electric quadrupole moment definition

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, tensor-calculus

I have encountered two (?) definitions of the electric quadrupole moment. They are:

$$Q_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\int \rho(\vec{x}')x'_i x'_j\,\mathrm{d}^3x'$$

and

$$Q_{ij}=\int (3x'_i x'_j-\delta_{ij}x'^2)\rho(\vec{x}')\,\mathrm{d}^3x'$$

I am trying to study radiation arising from the electric quadrupole. I am confused since sometimes the first definition is used while other times, the second. As such, which definition should be used and why?

Comment: Related: [Traceless multipole moments vs non-traceless moments](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/146777/traceless-multipole-moments-vs-non-traceless-moments)

Comment: Yes it does. In the case of say studying radiation arising from two like charges rotating about the axis centred at the origin, is it correct to then say I can use either expressions?